# How to search specific text on word and Pdf document quickly in c#?

Tags: c#, pdf, ms-word, find

Currently I am having more than 50000+ documents with the combination of both PDF & Word extension.

**Requirement / Workflow:**

- When user types a text with more than length of 8, we need to open and read all the documents, checks whether the typed text is available inside the document or not
- If the document has the user typed text, it needs to maintain in a separate list

Example:
If a user types "Notification", the process needs to open all the documents and check its pages whether the "Notification" text is present inside or not.
If its present in any of the specific document page, the document needs to maintain in a separate list

It needs to get achieved without much taking time

Comment: https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/ is a good lib for high performance queries of pdf documents. To be honest though - when talking about 50k documents, I'd suggest you use a search engine with indexing, that maybe also caches. Just the IO and CPU required to search 50k documents of say 1 MB each results in loading 50GB!! from a disk into RAM eventually and have a fulltext-search on it

Comment: Extrat all text from those. with something like apache Tika or any open document parser. Build a database with Elastique search. Add some fuzzy string on top. And bim